# How to loop through a generator, then yield the generator afterwards?

Tags: python, filesystems, yield

I want to copy the files being looped through the directory into a new folder, and I also want to add the file path to a csv, but I can't seem to do both in the same function.

```
import shapefile
import shutil, os
import csv

rasters = []
top = r"./test1"
def copy_filepaths(top):
    for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(top):
        if '__' in dirpath:
            continue
        shapefiles = filter(lambda f: f.endswith(".shp") and not f.startswith('.'), files)  # shapefiles only
        full_path_shapefiles = (os.path.join(dirpath, f) for f in shapefiles)  # build the full path

        for shapefile in full_path_shapefiles:
            shutil.copy(shapefile, './test1_copy')

        yield from full_path_shapefiles

filepaths = copy_filepaths(top)
for filepath in filepaths:
    with open(r'./shp_walker.csv', 'a+', newline='') as f:
        write = csv.writer(f)
        write.writerow([filepath])
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "at the same time?" Do you expect your function to run the for loop and `yield from` concurrently, or are you just are you just trying to do both in sequence, and running into the fact that you can't consume the same iterator twice?

Comment: I would say in sequence. Once it copys all the files to the new folder, I then want it to yield the result so I can add them to the csv.

Comment: In that case, `full_path_shapefiles` is a generator, so you can only consume (i.e., iterate over it) once. After the `for` loop finishes, any attempt to use `full_path_shapefiles` again will raise `StopIteration`. The easy fix would be to remove the `yield from` statement and instead add `yield shapefile` inside the `for` loop.

Comment: you have two generators. therefore use yield(next(full_path_shapefiles))

Answer (score 0):

```
import shapefile
import shutil, os
import csv

rasters = []
top = r"./test1"
def copy_filepaths(top):
    for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(top):
        if '__' in dirpath:
            continue
        shapefiles = filter(lambda f: f.endswith(".shx") and not f.startswith('.'), files)  # shapefiles only
        full_path_shapefiles = (os.path.join(dirpath, f) for f in shapefiles)  # build the full path

        for shapefile in full_path_shapefiles:
            shutil.copy(shapefile, './test1_copy')

            yield shapefile

filepaths = copy_filepaths(top)
for filepath in filepaths:
    with open(r'./shp_walker.csv', 'a+', newline='') as f:
        write = csv.writer(f)
        write.writerow([filepath])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always move the write operation into the `copy_filepaths()` function. You don't need to use a generator here. It also looks like `test1_copy` is constantly being overwritten, not sure if that is intentional or not.

```py
import shapefile
import shutil, os
import csv

rasters = []
top = r"./test1"
def copy_filepaths(top):
    for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(top):
        if '__' in dirpath:
            continue
        shapefiles = filter(lambda f: f.endswith(".shp") and not f.startswith('.'), files)  # shapefiles only
        full_path_shapefiles = (os.path.join(dirpath, f) for f in shapefiles)  # build the full path

        for shapefile in full_path_shapefiles:
            shutil.copy(shapefile, './test1_copy')
            with open(r'./shp_walker.csv', 'a+', newline='') as f:
                write = csv.writer(f)
                write.writerow([shapefile])
```